# Login as other user setting for other profile except System Adminsitrator

Tags: administration

If a user is setup as System Administrator profile, the user can login as other user. However, is there any option that I can enable this function for other profile except System Administrator because I don't want to give them other System Administrator permission access?

In the past as I remember in summer 12, there's an option called "managing user permission" which allow me to disable or enable the profile to login as other user. But I don't see this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [Delegated Administration](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_delegate.htm&siteLang=en_US), which lets you define whom can perform various administrative tasks, such as logging in as other users, configure custom objects, and assign user profiles. It's found in Setup > Security Controls > Delegated Administration.

Comment: Just about to post a similar response, but ya beat me to it :). As an additional note, you can allow admins to login as any sf user without needing to request permission. (needs to be turned on by SF first): https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=controlling_login_access.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Ricky, your comment is if the user is setup as System Administrator then they will have the ability of login as other user. But I want the non-System Administrator profile user to login as other user because I don't want to give this profile user full system administrator access.  I'm trying the Delegated Administration which was commented by sfdcfox.